# How can I start hadoop at boot time?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have a haddop 2.6.4 environment working well and using `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` to start it.

How can I start haddop at boot time using this scripts? Some tips around is using `start-all.sh` but it is deprecated.

Must I create two services in `init.d` ? What about all `EXPORT` stuff? Must  all nodes come in first?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a better place to ask is http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: I don't think so. I know how to make startup services in init.d. This case is hadoop specific because I need to know the implications of this procedure (the nodes and server startup order, the service startup order and if I need to start one by one of if there is a way to replace the obsolete `start-all.sh` to start all services at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use init.d and in your init.d script you should first export whatever env vars you will need. Then you can call your 2 start scripts or you can encapsulate the 2 scripts into one and use that. Look in init.d for examples.

Comment: is the startup order important? I mean, its ok if yarn start comes first?

Comment: Hadoop has many components, based on the 2 scripts you mention. You want to start DFS first and YARN next. You can refer to the deprecated start-all.sh script to get an idea of the start order used earlier. it has not changed, nodes and HDFS start first followed generally by resource managers

Comment: I asked this because I can't rely on startup order if I create two services for the two scripts. I don't know why `start-all.sh` becomes deprecated if it just make the start process easy... All examples on the net brings up DFS first so I don't know if it MUST or MAY be this way.